# Ansible debug is giving all meta data when going over loop

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to get a debug message from the results of a previous loop, but I can't get just the bit that I want from it. Ansible keeps giving me the entire result instead just the line I'm asking for.

Here are the 2 modules I'm using:

```
- name: Make the curl call
  uri:
    url: https://www.theurl.com
    method: GET
    return_content: yes
    headers:
      XXXX: "xxxxxxxxxx"
  loop: "{{ simplelist }}"
  register: this



 - name: just testing
    debug:
      msg: "I just want to see: {{ item.json.section.test }}"
    loop: "{{ this.results}}"
```

As you can see from the msg, I'm just trying to output that specific value, but what Ansible gives me is:

```
{
"ansible_loop_var": "item",
"_ansible_no_log": false,
"item": {
    "content_length": "",
    "cookies": {},
    "via": "1.1 varnish",
    "connection": "",
    "vary": "Accept-Encoding",
    "x_timer": "",
    "access_control_allow_methods": "OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, PATCH, DELETE",
    "x_cache_hits": "0",
    "failed": false,
    "access_control_allow_credentials": "true",
    "content": blah blah blah,
    "json": { the json },  
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "I just want to see: False",
```

So it is setting the message, as you can see from the last line, and it is getting the correct value, but it's not outputting that message. How can I get just the message to be output? I tested and I know that I can get the value because the msg has False and I tested with doing a fail/when with that value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing looks like a verbose output of ansible-playbook running with the `-v[vv]` option. You can drop that option to decrease verbosity.

Meanwhile, even in non-verbose mode, and whatever module your are using, when going over a loop, ansible outputs a `label` for each iteration, roughly looking like the following (watch for the `(item=....)` part of the screen).

```
TASK [test] *******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'a': 1, 'b': 2}) => {
    "msg": "This is the value of a: 1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'a': 3, 'b': 4}) => {
    "msg": "This is the value of a: 3"
}
```

By default, the label is a the full item your are currently looping over. But you can change this label in the `loop_control` parameter which can be a little too verbose for complex data structures. If you really want an empty label your can use the following example. But you will still get `ok: [server1] => (item=) =>` prepended to each iteration output.

```
 - name: just testing
   debug:
     msg: "I just want to see: {{ item.json.section.test }}"
   loop: "{{ this.results }}"
   loop_control:
     label: ""
```

For more info see  [limiting loop output with `label`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#limiting-loop-output-with-label)

Comment: I'm using Ansible Tower, and I have verbose set to 0(normal). I had to set my label to item.json.section.test to get it to do what I wanted, but It did clean up my console.