# Ansible debug module print undesired details

Tags: amazon-s3, ansible

I have the following playbook which simply get ec2_info and I would like to only print to the console the state and launch times. However, my debug info is very verbose, printing all facts known. How can I force the debug out to only print the msg

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

    - name: ec2 instance info
      ec2_instance_info:
        aws_access_key: "{{ AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}"
        aws_secret_key: "{{ AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}"
        aws_region: "{{ AWS_REGION }}"
      register: result

    - name: display ec2 info
      debug:
        msg: 
          - "Instance {{ item.launch_time }}"
          - "Instance {{ item.state }}"
      with_items:
        - "{{ result.instances }}"
```

The output of the debug module - Information from the item={} has been removed for security reason.

```
ok: [localhost] => (item={redacted for security reasons}) => { 
    "msg": [
        "Instance 2020-09-11T18:15:08+00:00",
        "Instance {'code': 80, 'name': 'stopped'}"
    ]
}
```

My goal is to print:

```
"msg": [
    "Instance 2020-09-11T18:15:08+00:00",
    "Instance {'code': 80, 'name': 'stopped'}"
]
```

Comment: see [limiting loop output with `label`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#limiting-loop-output-with-label)

Comment: See also this duplicate: [Ansible debug is giving all meta data when going over loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60530530/ansible-debug-is-giving-all-meta-data-when-going-over-loop)

Comment: I'm looping over a complex structure. I will have to experiment a bit to determine the loop function will work.

Comment: `loop_control: {label: ""}` is a very good start to experiment.

Comment: can you provide an example of how I could apply this to the result of ec2_instance_info module registered var?

Comment: I already did in my last comment. This will give you an empty item display on each loop iteration. Then adapt to your needs.